# How to format invalid xml in Notepad++?

Tags: xml, notepad++, code-formatting

I've got Notepad++ and XML Tools plugin. I want to know how can I format invalid code like this:

```xml
aaa<a><z/></a>
```

It should be formatted like this:

```xml
aaa
<a>
    <z/>
</a>
```

When I tried to use XML Tools plugin with this example obviously I receive this error:

> "Errors detected in content...".

I saw it is possible, but I don't know how.
What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Which XML Tools command are you using? Formatting with "**Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks)**" (shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) works for me.

Before:

[image]

After <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

I get the same error you reported using:

- Pretty print (attributes)
- Pretty print (libXML) [experimental]

[image]

Comment: I have `Notepad++ v.7.5.5` and `XML Tools Plugin version 2.3.2 unicode beta4 r908` and I tried all Pretty print possibities. Which XML Tools Plugin version do you have?

Comment: @LukaszRe I'm using `Notepad++ 7.5.3` and `XML Tools Plugin version 2.4.9.2 unicode`

Answer (score 0):

XML Pretty printers can only deal with vaid XML.
Use NotePad++ Plugin 'XML Fools, Select only the text within the CData, and format only that (Valid XML).